# jQuery select children of children of children etc

Tags: jquery

How do you target the children of children indefinately in jQuery. I can find the first level children using `.children()` but can't go any deeper than that.

```
$('[data-snap-ignore="true"]').children().attr('data-snap-ignore', true);
```

I am basically having to find an element with attribute data-snap-ignore="true" and add that attribute to every child, grandchild, great grandchild and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .find('*')

```
$('[data-snap-ignore="true"]').find('*').attr('data-snap-ignore', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way : this will find all children's having attribute '`data-snap-ignore`'

Further Reading : [.find()](http://jqapi.com/#p=find)

```
$('[data-snap-ignore="true"]').find('[data-snap-ignore]');
```

Comment: sorry I haven't phrased my question brilliantly. Only the parent element has the attribute 'data-snap-ignore', im trying to find all children and add that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ch = $('[data-snap-ignore="true"]').children(); //returns all children
$.each(ch, function (i, j) {
    $(j).attr('data-snap-ignore', true);
});
```